# Creating Matrix in Stata

Tags: stata

I am simulating pga tournaments using Stata. My simulation results table consists of:

column 1: the names of the 30 players in the tournament
columns 2 - 30,001: the 4 round results of my monte-carol simulations.

what I am trying to do is create a 30 x 30 matrix with the golfers' names as column 1 and across the column names where each cell represents the percentage of times Golfer A beat Golfer B outright from the 30,000 simulations. Is this possible to do in Stata? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please review [StackOverflow - How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with regards to the way you should ask and what your question should include. You should show attempts of code in your question so that members of the community can assist you and provide you with more accurate responses.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to say that everything is always possible in all programming languages, but somethings are much more difficult to do in some languages compared to others. I do not think that Stata is great tool for what you intend to do.

You need to provide some code examples for us to be able to help you with your task, but here is one thing I can say. Stata has two programming languages. One is often called Stata (but is called `ado` on Stata Corps webiste) and the other is `Mata`. If you for some reason need to use the software Stata, you should do this in the language `Mata` that has more matrix operators than `ado`. And in `ado` you cant store text in a matrix, so if you want to store the name of the golfer you need to use `Mata`, but you can also use indexes of rows and columns to keep track of the golfers.

With that said, Stata is primarily a tool to make operations and analyze a single dataset loaded into memory (recently support for multiple datasets has been added). So to answer your question, yes, this ***can*** be done in Stata, but you are probably much better of doing it in a language with more support for multidimensional arrays/vectors. For example, R or Python.